# Floor Joist Tolerances

Tags: joists

What is an acceptable tolerance for floor joists (subfloor not laid, yet) over a 4 ft span in an old home? How far out (in height) is acceptable?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? There is a lot more info needed than your question provides

Comment: Sounds like Laxmidi is asking min. dim. of FJ over a 4'0" span.  A Hem.Fir. / Pine 2x4 would be fine @ 16" center (spaced apart).  Though anything less than 2x6 would make me uncomfortable re: deflection.